# Remove special character from a file without any extension in order to make it a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, special-characters

I have a file without any extension. I want to convert it to a dataframe in python but it doesn't let me because it says it has too many columns than expected because | is the delimiter and I also have it inside two ".

It is possible to remove only the | that is between two "" using python? Tried with regex but it won't let me to convert it to a dataframe so I need to do this before.

I can't convert it to dataframe because it has | as a column delimiter end the column end has 27x |.

As example, I just open the file that doesn't has an extension with file = f'test' and then I convert it to dataframe but the fact that it has that | between those "" it doesn't let me to make it df because it detects too many columns. Any other ideas?

Example of rows in the file:

```
Details|145|Sam's Garden|Retail|12.0|"It's a nice | garden"| USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Details|200|That's my thing|Retail|23.4|"Not so | great"|EUR|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

So I need to delete that | from "It's a nice | garden" and from "Not so | great" but don't know how can I process the data from the file without an extension.

At the moment I am opening the file in VSCode and search for " I am deleting that |, save the file and then convert it to a dataframe in python in order to export it as csv. Any idea is apreciated!

Comment: Did you try setting `quotechar`?

Comment: How to use it? This is used when reading a csv file, right? I have a file without extension reading it as file = f"file"

Comment: You can read any text file with the `csv` package. The extension is not important here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `quoting` parameter of `read_csv`:

```
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('file', sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, header=None)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        0    1                2       3     4                     5     6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
0  Details  145     Sam's Garden  Retail  12.0  It's a nice | garden   USD NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  Details  200  That's my thing  Retail  23.4        Not so | great   EUR NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Update**

Try using `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('file') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
```

Comment: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 161

Comment: @Pythonless. I updated my answer, can you check it please? I don't know if your file contains header or not.

Comment: unicodedecodeerror: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 6127: character maps to <undefinded>